# How to disable command button before the action?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, commandbutton, disable

Please help! I need that the button "Save" to be inactive before the user changes the Status in position.  I tried to do this with disabled="{! If (Status==null, true, false)}". But it didn`t work. How can I do this?

The code for the "Save" button in my controller:

```
public PageReference save() {  
    update Position;    
    if (Status == null) {
        Position = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c, Open_date__c, Closed_date__c,
                Min_pay__c, Max_pay__c FROM Position__c];
    }
    else {
        Position = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c, Open_date__c, Closed_date__c,
                Min_pay__c, Max_pay__c FROM Position__c WHERE Status__c =: Status];
    }
    return null;     
}
```

}

My visualforce page:

```
            <apex:pageBlockTable id="positionTable" value="{! Position }" var="pos">
                <apex:column headerValue="Positions name">
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!URLFOR(pos.id)}">{!pos.name}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>  
                <apex:column headerValue="Status" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{! pos.Status__c }"/>                    
                </apex:column> 
                <apex:column headerValue="Open Date" value="{! pos.Open_date__c }"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Close Date" value="{! pos.Closed_date__c }"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Max Pay" value="{! pos.Max_pay__c }"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Min Pay" value="{! pos.Min_pay__c }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>          

            <apex:commandButton value="Save" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `pos` in the header; you'll need a separate variable to make it work:

```
public Position__c templatePosition { get; set; }
// Constructor should have:
public MyController() {
  templatePosition = new Position__c();
}
```

Next, add an `apex:actionSupport` to your picklist, and use the templatePosition variable:

```
<apex:inputField value="{! templatePosition.Status__c }">
  <apex:actionSupport rerender="saveButton" event="onchange" />
</apex:inputField>
```

Then add an `id`, `disabled`, and `action` to your button:

```
<apex:commandButton id="saveButton" 
  value="Save" 
  action="{!save}" 
  disabled="{!templatePosition.Status__c=''}" />
```

Note that using various Boolean comparison operators, are already true/false values, so you don't need an `if` function.

Finally, in your save method, apply the position to each record before saving:

```
public void save() {
    for(Position__c record: positions) {
      record.Status__c = templatePosition.Status__c;
    }
    update Position;    
}
```

This isn't the only possible configuration; you could also do this in pure JavaScript.

```
<!-- must be before apex:pageBlockTable -->
<script>
function updateSaveButton(event) {
  const itemSelected = event.target.selectedIndex > 0;
  const saveButton = document.getElementById('{!$Component.saveButton}');
  saveButton.disabled = !itemSelected;
}
</script>
```

...

```
<apex:inputField value="{! templatePosition.Status__c }" onchange="updateSaveButton(event)" />
```

Which executes faster, but may require additional logic to get it exactly right, since Visualforce makes the `id` variable depending on how the button is positioned related to other elements.

Comment: Thank you! With JavaScript the disabled button activated after change status in position, but do not save.